# S71200 LSQL-Microsoft, Datatype changed, after copying Function Block - How do I fix this?

Tags: sql, st, siemens, tia-portal

I am integrating SQL-Connection to one or our existing Siemens S7-1200 PLCs right now.
After copying a Function Block from a working project, one of the data types has changed and is causing trouble now.

Original:

[image]

Copied FB:

[image]

Does anybody know, how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using the same version of TIA portal?  What version?  Can you translate the error message in the yellow box to english?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone in the Siemens-Forum could answer my question right away.
Leaving his answer here for the next person with my problem :

> With the introduction of the OUC library in version V4.x, the TCON instruction, among other things, has changed. Try to update the program on the CPU. In this case, the prerequisite is that the CPU must have at least firmware version V4.1. There is also the risk that translation errors will occur in other places where the older versions were previously used. In this case, the PLC code would have to be adjusted accordingly.